# Example of KNN overfitting with low K

Tags: knn, nearest-neighbor, overfitting-underfitting

I know that with k=1 a KNN lead to overfitting, this is because it follows the noisy data of the training sample and not generalize well on new input sample. But I am confused on how this happens, I understand the graphics but cant't figure out an example. For instance, why in the training data noise are followed and in test data not ? if someone can please give me an example, I'll be grateful.

Thanks to all :).